# How many character slots do you get?

Tags: the-secret-world

By default, how many character slots do you get in The Secret World with the various purchasing options? One option has "+1 character slot" as a perk, which made me wonder about the default case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default starting number of slots is **three**.

You can purchase more individually, for **$9.99** (US) each, or get them as part of various packages such as the starter kits.

Comment: And keep in mind that there's basically no reason to run more that 3 slots, unless you insist on doing Fusang on *every dimension* for some reason.  Really no reason for more than one unless you want to experience all the faction-specific content (which isn't that extensive compared to the rest of the game).